# Changing Application Theme on Android for PhoneGap App (using phonegap Build)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using PhoneGap Build, and I want to change the Theme for my Android application from the default Dark to Holo Light.

Any idea how can I do it?

Can I create a plugin that changes the `AndroidManifest.xml` file maybe?

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at [this post](http://teusink.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/android-example-app-with-phonegap-and.html) , maybe it is the right way to go

Edit: Hole Theme for JQuery Mobile can be downloaded [here](http://teusink.blogspot.nl/2012/09/android-holo-theme-for-jquery-mobile-111.html)